# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Getting error while trying to run Spring Boot Application on Eureka Server.
Here I am trying to do Fault Tolerance in the Application.

I have created three Applications:

1. CitizenServer
2. EurekaServer
3. VaccinationServer

In order to check whether the Fault Tolerance is working or not I have started EurekaServer and Vaccination Server.

[image: Here I have closed the CitizenServer]

Here I have closed the CitizenServer. In order to check the Fault Tolerance.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>



<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MicroserviceVaccinationCenter</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MicroserviceVaccinationCenter</name>
<description>Microservice for Vaccination Center</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

VaccinationController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/vaccinationcenter")
public class VaccinationCenterController {

@Autowired
private CenterRepo centerRepo;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@PostMapping(
        path = {"/add"}
    )
    public ResponseEntity<VaccinationCenter> addCitizen(@RequestBody VaccinationCenter vaccinationCenter) {
        VaccinationCenter vaccinationCenterAdded = (VaccinationCenter)this.centerRepo.save(vaccinationCenter);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(vaccinationCenterAdded, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@GetMapping(path = {"/id/{id}"})
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "handleCitizenDownTime")
    public ResponseEntity<RequiredResponse> getAllDadaBasedonCenterId(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        RequiredResponse requiredResponse = new RequiredResponse();
        VaccinationCenter center = centerRepo.findById(id).get();
        requiredResponse.setCenter(center);
        

        List<Citizen> listOfCitizens = restTemplate.getForObject("http://CITIZEN-SERVICE/citizen/id/"+id, List.class);
        requiredResponse.setCitizens(listOfCitizens);
        return new ResponseEntity<RequiredResponse>(requiredResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

public ResponseEntity<RequiredResponse> handleCitizenDownTime(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    RequiredResponse requiredResponse = new RequiredResponse();
    VaccinationCenter center = centerRepo.findById(id).get();
    requiredResponse.setCenter(center);
    return new ResponseEntity<RequiredResponse>(requiredResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    
} }
```

Output Terminal:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-22 19:37:03.465 ERROR 20100 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.microservice.VaccinationCenter.MicroserviceVaccinationCenterApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.microservice.VaccinationCenter.MicroserviceVaccinationCenterApplication.main(MicroserviceVaccinationCenterApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1090) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1071) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:522) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```